# If else statement skips during second call

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

This is the while loop that calls a method x amount of times.

```
while (count<=rounds){
    System.out.println("Round " + round);
    PlayerVsPlayer.results();
    count++;
    round++;            
}
```

PlayerVsPlayer.results() asks for user input and calls another statement.

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors:");
        String Player1 = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors:");
        String Player2= scan.nextLine();
        String[] Results = compare.winScore(Player1, Player2);
```

This is a snippet of the if else statement in compare.winScore(Player1, Player2) :

```
static String[] winScore(String x, String y){

    if (x.equals(y)) {
        winnerScoreRule.add("Round results is a tie, no one wins.");
        winnerScoreRule.add("");
        winnerScoreRule.add("");
    }
    else if ((x.equals("Rock")) && (y.equals("Paper"))){
        score2++; count++;
        winnerScoreRule.add("Player 2 wins this round!");
        winnerScoreRule.add("The score is " + score1 +" to "+ score2);
        winnerScoreRule.add("Paper beats rock!"); // etc.
    }
```

The problem that I'm having is that the first time the if else statement executes, it works perfectly. The second time around, the if else statement skips and returns the values from the first call. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you call using the same values or different values? What values?

Comment: Odds are about 99.9997 to 1 that the error is in your code rather than in Java. Try printing out x and y on entry to `winScore()`.

Comment: You're asking user to choose R, P and S. Then comparing with Rock and Paper. Also, it does not limit the users from entering anything they want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite this winScore method to check for "other" cases.

```
static String[] winScore(String x, String y){

        if (x.equals(y)) {
            winnerScoreRule.add("Round results is a tie, no one wins.");
            winnerScoreRule.add("");
            winnerScoreRule.add("");
        }
    //you're asking them to enter (R), (P) or (S)
        else if ((x.toLowerCase().equals("r")) && (y.toLowerCase().equals("p"))){
            score2++; count++;
            winnerScoreRule.add("Player 2 wins this round!");
            winnerScoreRule.add("The score is " + score1 +" to "+ score2);
            winnerScoreRule.add("Paper beats rock!"); // etc.
        }
       ....//other logic for Rock Paper Scissors
        else
       {
           throw WrongOptionSelectedException(); //custom exception for wrong entry
        }
```